# Close Overlay and Redirect to Custom URL on Save-Node in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal

When my node form saves, I want to close the admin overlay and redirect to a custom URL that is stored with the node. hook_form_alter() is setting $form['#redirect'] but I think that would only work with no admin overlay.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used it before myself, but i think you can call the overlay_close_dialog(...) function from your hook_submit

See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--overlay--overlay.module/function/overlay_close_dialog/7 for more info

Answer (score 1):

Kept googling my way here and wanted to post a final solution that worked for me on Drupal 7 (got here thanks to [jakraska](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1161346/jakraska)'s suggestion).  First use [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) to hook into the specific form you want to alter

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()
* 
**/
function mymodule_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_callback';
}
```

Then write your callback that will render the page.  In my case I simply wanted to close the overlay, so that's why I used the $form_state['redirect'] = FALSE;

```
function mymodule_callback(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Form API will re-render the current page and pass the redirect information to the overlay JavaScript 
  overlay_close_dialog();
  // stay on the same page after all submit callbacks have been processed.
  $form_state['redirect'] = FALSE;
}
```

If you want to redirect to another path, 
See https://api.acquia.com/api/drupal/modules!overlay!overlay.module/function/overlay_form_submit/7 - I believe that should get you there.

Answer (score 1):

Kept googling my way here as well.. this is the working solution:

Inside your form:

```
$form['somebutton']['#submit'] = array('your_custom_callback');
```

Add a custom callback

```
function your_custom_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  //redirect users to Drupal.org
  $url = "http://drupal.org";

  if (module_exists('overlay') && overlay_get_mode() == 'child') {
    unset($_GET['destination']);
    overlay_close_dialog($url, array('external' => TRUE));
    $form_state['redirect'] = FALSE;
  } else {
    $form_state['redirect'] = $url;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;` inside your `hook_submit` function, otherwise it would not close overlay after form is submitted.